# Open and connected set in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

In a normed space, we know that if a set is open and connected, it is path connected. Is it true for general metric space or general topological space?

Comment: Not true in general for topological spaces. Consider for example the "long line topology" which is built from gluing uncountably many $[0, 1)$s together + a positive infinity at one end. The simple fact is that even though it's connected, it's just too long for there to be a continuous map from $[0, 1]$ so that $0 \mapsto 0$ and $1 \mapsto \infty$.

Comment: @A.P. it doesn't discuss metric space there.

Answer (score 1):

For general topological spaces the answer is no. See here for a nice counterexample, the union of the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ and $\{0\}$:

http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Connected_not_implies_path-connected

If your space is locally path-connected, i.e. every point has a path-connected neighborhood, then connected implies path connected.
This particularly holds for normed vector spaces, since any open ball around a point is path-connected.

So for metric spaces, connectedness and path-connectedness are equivalent, but for general topological spaces not.

Comment: how to prove any open ball around a point is path-connected?

Comment: Sorry, my original statement was wrong. The question of local path-connectedness is more sophisticated than I thought...

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.  The typical counterexample is the "[topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve)".
$$\{(t,\sin(1/t):t>0\}\cup \{(0,y):-1\le y\le 1\}.$$